# How to multiply the elements within a vector using matrix operations (e.g., dot product)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Suppose a vector $\vec{v}^T=(v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n)^T$. To sum the elements within the vector, I can use the dot product with a column vector of ones, $\sum_i v_i = \vec{v}^T \cdot \vec{1}$.

My question is, what is the equivalent set of matrix operations to get the multiplication of the elements, $\prod_i v_i$?

My first pass over this problem:

The first thing that came to mind, was to generate a vector of the logarithm of the elements, $\vec{w}^T=(\ln v_1, \ldots, \ln v_n)^T$, multiply with a vector of ones as before, and then exponentiate. This way, $\prod_i v_i=\exp\left(\vec{w}^T\cdot\vec{1}\right)$.

However, the elements in my original vector $\vec{v}$ are natural numbers, including $0$'s, so taking logarithms is not an option.

Help is appreciated!

Comment: Why not add 1 to every element, perform the logarithm and exponentations, then subtract 1? This will remove any instances of 0 and recover at the end

Comment: @Nitin Because that would give the wrong result. For example, if $\vec{v} = (1,0)$ then $v_1 v_2 = 0$ but $(v_1 + 1)(v_2 + 1) - 1 = 1$.

Comment: @Andres Gomez-Lievano: Just say that if $v_i = 0$ for some $i$ then $\prod_i v_i = 0$, otherwise go ahead with the logarithms and exponential. Also, note that you cannot compute $p(\vec{v}) = \prod_i v_i$ relying only on matrix operations, because $p$ isn't a linear function. This means that if you do wish to use matrix operations then you have to linearise your problem (i.e. take logarithms) at some point.